# how does derivation work in Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: tensors

When I apply the four gradient operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ on a scalar which is the contraction of a four vector, for example $x_{\mu} x^{\mu}$, do i need to convert first the scalar expression to a controvariant form (given that the variable wich we derive w.r.t. is controvariant as well)?
So that i have $\frac{\partial (x_{\mu} x^{\mu})}{\partial 
 x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial ((x^0)^2-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^3)^2)}{\partial x^{\mu}} = 2x_{\mu}$ and I'm deriving an expression of the same type as the derivation variable.

Comment: $\frac{\partial (x_{\mu} x^{\mu})}{\partial 
 x^{\mu}}$ is better written as $\frac{\partial (x_{\color{red}\nu}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial 
 x^{\mu}}\,.$ Do you know why? This is equal to $\frac{\eta_{\nu\rho}\partial (x^{\rho} x^{\nu})}{\partial 
 x^{\mu}}\,.$ Hint: when doing the derivative beware of the sign of $\eta_{\nu\rho}\,.$

Comment: Thank you, you are right it would have been better using a different symbol (I will leave it like this for clarification). My question was more of the sort: do I consider $x_{\mu}$ and $x^{\mu}$ as different variables, so that when I derive $x^{\mu}$ by $x_{\mu}$ I first need to convert it to its covariant form and then derive (obtaining in this case -1) or is there another way to perform such a derivation?

Comment: That is the only right way. When the metric is no longer constant it becomes even more important.