# Problems differentiating four-vectors to find the equation of motion using Euler-Lagrange equations.

Tags: proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, tensors, euler-lagrange-equation, quantum-field-theory

This post directly follows this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862992/using-euler-lagrange-equations-show-that-the-following-eom-can-be-written-as-d) and is very similar in nature:

> Consider the following Lagrangian:
> $$\mathcal{L}=\frac14\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu\right)\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)+\partial_\mu\phi^\ast\partial^\mu\phi$$
> $$+ieA^\mu\left(\phi\partial_\mu\phi^\ast - \phi^\ast\partial_\mu\phi\right)
> +e^2A_\mu A^\mu\phi^\ast\phi-m^2\phi^\ast\phi-\frac12\lambda\left(\phi^\ast\phi\right)^2\tag{1}$$
> [...]
>
> The equation of motion obtained from the Lagrangian, $(1)$, for $A_\color{red}{\mu}$ is more interesting,
> $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu A_\nu}=ie\left(\phi\partial_{\color{red}{\nu}}\phi^\ast-\phi^\ast\partial_{\color{red}{\nu}}\phi\right)$$
> $$+2e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi-\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)=0\tag{2}$$
> This can be written as
> $$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=ie\left[\phi\left(D^\nu\phi\right)^\ast-\phi^\ast D^\nu\phi\right]\tag{3}$$

---

Where $F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$ and $D^\nu\phi\equiv \partial^\nu\phi + ieA^\nu\phi$ - similar to the previous question.

Before even doing any calculations I believe there are some typos present on the indices I marked in red. In particular, I think the $A_\mu$ should be $A^\nu$ as there is no equation of motion for $A_\mu$: equation $(2)$ does not even contain $A_\mu$.
I think the corrected version of $(2)$ should read
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu A_\nu}=ie\left(\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-\phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi\right)$$
$$+2e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi-\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)=0\tag{A}$$

A quick check is needed to make sure equation $(\mathrm{A})$ is actually correct, to verify this I will use it to prove eqn. $(3)$:
$$\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)=\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}$$
$$=ie\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-ie\phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi+e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi+e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi$$
$$ie\phi\left(\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-ieA^\nu\phi^\ast\right)-ie\phi^\ast\left(\partial^\nu\phi+ieA^\nu\phi\right)$$
$$=ie\left[\phi\left(D^\nu\phi\right)^\ast-\phi^\ast D^\nu\phi\right]$$
which is eqn. $(3)$, so equation $(\mathrm{A})$ appears correct.

---

**The objective is now to prove equation $(\mathrm {A})$**:

To make the proof easier I first rewrite the Lagrangian, $(1)$ as
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac14\partial_\mu A_\nu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)+\frac14\partial_\nu A_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)$$
$$+ieA_\nu\left(\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast - \phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi\right)
+e^2A_\nu A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi$$
$$-m^2\phi^\ast\phi-\frac12\lambda\left(\phi^\ast\phi\right)^2+\partial_\mu\phi^\ast\partial^\mu\phi$$
where in the second line of eqn. $(1)$ I lowered and raised the respective indices on the terms involving $A^\mu \partial_\mu\phi$ and let $\mu\to \nu$ in these terms and the next term involving $e^2$.
So
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu}=ie\left(\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-\phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi\right)+e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi$$
and
$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu A_\nu}=-\frac14\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)$$
Putting these together gives
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu}-\partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu A_\nu}$$
$$=ie\left(\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-\phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi\right)+e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi+\frac14\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)=0\tag{!}$$
But this is not the same as equation $(\mathrm{A})$:
$$ie\left(\phi\partial^\nu\phi^\ast-\phi^\ast\partial^\nu\phi\right)
+2e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi-\partial_\mu\left(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu\right)=0\tag{A}$$
differing by a factor of $2$ and $1/4$ in the second and third terms, respectively. I'm sure equation $(\mathrm{A})$ is the correct one as I derived eqn. $(3)$ from it. It is likely I am making mistakes in $(\mathrm{!})$, but I just cannot seem to find them.

May I please have some help in proving eqn. $(\mathrm{A})$ or identifying errors in $(\mathrm{!})$?

Comment: That post contains a lot of questions. "equation (2) does not even contain $A_\mu$" Imo it does. Raise the index of $A$ and contract with the metric and  $A_\mu$ enters the stage. Similar things were discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859901/how-does-derivation-work-in-minkowski-spacetime#comment10359259_4859901). Please think about this and reduce this post to a parsimonious size.

Comment: @KurtG. "That post contains a lot of questions." No, there is only one question here, and that question is how to prove eqn. $(\mathrm{A})$. I even put it in boldface for clarity. What other questions do you see in this post? "[...] reduce this post to a parsimonious size". If I do that I cannot show my working and hence convey my confusion/lack of understanding. Do you think I enjoy writing long posts?

Comment: I have already highlighted a misconception you had. You should address that. I usually stop reading long posts when there is some disagreement about the basics.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, I checked that link and am now very confused, in particular I don't know how to deal with derivatives of four-vectors, for instance, in the question of the link you posted I thought that $\frac{\partial (x_{\mu} x^{\mu})}{\partial   x^{\mu}}=x_\mu$ and I don't know why the OP wrote $2x_\mu$. You call this "the basics" yet I have not come across it. Moreover, in your first comment in that link you write that $\frac{\eta_{\nu\rho}\partial (x^{\rho} x^{\nu})}{\partial   x^{\mu}}$ and caution the OP to take care when doing the derivative, I would not know how to take the compute ..

Comment: ... the derivative when the Minkowski metric is involved. For the case of my question this could explain the factor of $2$ in front of the $e^2A^\nu\phi^\ast\phi$ term if writing $A^\nu=\eta^{\sigma\nu}A_\sigma$. But that still doesn't explain the factor of $1/4$ in front of the field strength tensor, $F^{\mu\nu}$. While I acknowledge that hints/tips are more useful to someone when learning, but in this case could you please be at bit less cryptic? I mean, you've pointed out where I am going wrong but haven't yet said what is the correct thing to do (at least to start) to prove $(\mathrm{A})$.

Comment: The reason I am terse is that is that I want OPs to learn it themselves in their own words. So you are still confused about the linked post? There are in fact some issues I have not noticed yet. That derivatives term is better written as $\frac{\partial (x_{\color{red}\nu}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x_{\color{red}\mu}}\,.$ We know that that is $\frac{\partial (\eta_{\color{red}\nu\rho}\,x^{\rho}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x_{\color{red}\mu}}\,.$

Comment: That is now a matter of differentiating a homogeneous
polynomial in $(x_0,...,x_3)$ of degree two w.r.t. $x_\mu\,.$ It should be obvious that the matter is far more complicated when the metric depends on $(x_0,...,x_3)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. "The reason I am terse is that is that I want OPs to learn it themselves in their own words." Yes! and I agree with this, this style of teaching is normally the best way for one to learn, as you say the OP learns in their own words. But this method doesn't always work though. For example, you've just given two more cryptic comments, yep I see that  $\frac{\partial (x_{\color{red}\nu}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x_{\color{red}\mu}}=\frac{\partial (\eta_{\color{red}\nu\rho}\,x^{\rho}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x_{\color{red}\mu}}$, but so what? Sorry, I just don't get it.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you very much for trying to help me though, I do appreciate your time and effort! I'm just very confused by the linked post as well as this post. I hate to ask this, but this is one case where I don't think I will understand unless it is spelled out for me. Would you consider making an answer please? As I think more comments will just confuse me even more, sorry about this!

Comment: "So what?" Since $\eta_{\nu\rho}=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ we have $\frac{\partial (\eta_{\color{red}\nu\rho}\,x^{\rho}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x_{\color{red}\mu}}=-x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\,.$ Can you differentiate this w.r.t. $x_\mu\,?$ These are the basics I am missing your reactions on. As long as I hear "so what?" on my hints I will not deliver the derivation of (A) on the silver plate.

Comment: BTW the factor $2$ that you are missing in (!) is missing *precisely* because of refusing to differentiate the 2nd order homogeneous polynomial that I mentioned before and that I just spelled out expressis verbis to give you the very last hint. Case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key things  that lead to the correct factors in (A) are

- the basic expression $A_\mu A^\mu=\eta^{\mu\rho}A_\mu A_\rho=-A_0^2+A_1^2+A_2^2+A_3^2$ in (1) from OP that you have to differentiate w.r.t. each of $A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3\,.$ This differentiation obviously yields (basic calculus)
  $-2A_0,+2A_1,+2A_2,+2A_3$ respectively. This can be written as
  $$\tag{1}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial A_\nu}(A_\mu A^\mu)=2\eta^{\nu\rho}A_\rho=2A^\nu
  $$
  (c.f. (A)).
- To the term $F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}=(\partial_\alpha A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha)(\partial^\alpha A^\beta-\partial^\beta A^\alpha)$ we are now going to apply the same basic rules:
  \begin{align}\tag{2}
  &(\partial_\alpha A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha)(\partial^\alpha A^\beta-\partial^\beta A^\alpha)=
  (\partial_\alpha A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha)\,\underbrace{\eta^{\alpha\rho}\eta^{\beta\sigma}
  (\partial_\rho A_\sigma-\partial_\sigma A_\rho)}
  \end{align}
  From $\eta^{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)\,,$ the underbraced
  term is numerically equal to
  \begin{align}
  \cases{0&$\alpha=\beta\,,$\\[2mm]
  -(\partial_\color{red}{0} A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\color{red}{0})\,,&$\beta=1,2,3\,,$\\[2mm]
  -(\partial_\alpha A_\color{red}{0}-\partial_\color{red}{0} A_\alpha)\,,&$\alpha=1,2,3\,,$\\[2mm]
  (\partial_\alpha A_\beta-\partial_\beta A_\alpha)\,,&$\alpha,\beta=1,2,3,\alpha\not=\beta\,.$\\
  }
  \end{align}
  This leads to
  \begin{align}
  \\[2mm]
  (2)&=-F_{01}^2-F_{02}^2-F_{03}^2+F_{12}^2+F_{13}^2+F_{23}^2
  -F_{10}^2-F_{20}^2-F_{30}^2+F_{21}^2+F_{31}^2+F_{32}^2\\[2mm]
  &=-2F_{01}^2-2F_{02}^2-2F_{03}^2+2F_{12}^2+2F_{13}^2+2F_{23}^2\,.
  \end{align}
  The last line uses again that $F_{\alpha\beta}$ is anti symmetric which makes $F_{\alpha\beta}^2$ symmetric.
  Differentiating this w.r.t. $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ for a fixed index pair $\mu,\nu$ gives
  $$
  \frac{\partial F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}=\cases{-4\,F_{\color{red}{0}\nu}=-4\,(\partial_\color{red}{0} A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\color{red}{0})\,,&$\nu=1,2,3\,,$\\[2mm]
  -4\,F_{\mu\color{red}{0}}=-4\,(\partial_\mu A_\color{red}{0}-\partial_\color{red}{0} A_\mu)\,,&$\mu=1,2,3\,,$\\[2mm]
  4\,F_{\mu\nu}=4\,(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)\,,&$\mu,\nu=1,2,3\,.$}
  $$
  This can be written as
  $$
  \frac{\partial F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}
  =4\,\eta^{\mu\rho}\eta^{\nu\sigma}\,F_{\rho\sigma}=4\,F^{\mu\nu}=4\,(\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu)\,.
  $$
  This confirms again what we see in (A): the $\frac14$ cancels and a minus sign
  comes from $-\partial_\mu\frac{\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}\,.$

Comment: and similarly for the $\mu=0$ case in $\frac{\partial F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$ expression. Otherwise your answer makes perfect sense. Sorry haven't had time to look at your answer until today. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, now it is clear. Just one more question for you if I may, in my (now deleted answer) I wrote $\frac{\partial (\eta_{\color{red}\nu\rho}\,x^{\rho}\,x^{\color{red}\nu})}{\partial   x^{\color{red}\mu}}=-\frac{\partial \left(x^0\right)^2}{\partial x^0}+\frac{\partial \left(x^1\right)^2}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial \left(x^2\right)^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial\left(x^3\right)^2}{\partial x^3}=2\left(-x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3\right)=2\eta_{\sigma\mu}x^\sigma=2x_\mu$ and you wrote a comment below saying....

Comment: .... "The expressions $-\frac{\partial \left(x^0\right)^2}{\partial x^0}+\frac{\partial \left(x^1\right)^2}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial \left(x^2\right)^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial\left(x^3\right)^2}{\partial x^3}$ and $2(-x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3)$ are garbage" Do you mean 'garbage' as in unnecessary steps that are not needed or garbage as in mathematically incorrect? I'm sure what I wrote was perfectly fine mathematically, but now you have me questioning this.

Comment: @SiriusBlack let me know if you cannot see that deleted answer so that I can better refer to it. Hints: that derivative is not a sum over $\mu\,$ and your end result $2x_\mu$ needs a minus sign when $\mu=0.$

Comment: Thanks, I can see the deleted answer, but I don't think you can. I have therefore copied the contents of that answer as a new answer (it's really a comment, but too long). It should never have been deleted in the first place.

Comment: @SiriusBlack Users with 10k rep can see deleted questions and answers. Back to math: is it all clear now?

Comment: Yes all clear, no repeated index so I should not have summed the components, and the minus sign in the $2x_\mu$ depends on the metric convention (+,-,-,-) or (-,+,+,+).  Thanks very much for your time and help, it is most appreciated.